# How can I access data in my database? - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, view

I am using CodeIgniter and have a login system. I am still fairly new with php and I am wondering  once the user is logged in, how I can access his/her data to use throughout the site? Right now I am trying to make it say welcome "username" but I dont know where the variables come from and how I should use them. Right now in my home_view.php I have:

```
    <div class="main">
    <h2>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>!</h2>
</div>
```

It throws this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: username

Filename: views/home_view.php

Line Number: 22
```

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Have you read the user guide? I highly recommend you read the introduction tutorial. This will guide you through the basics of retrieving and setting data to/from the database, and displaying it in views: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: You may also consider working with just PHP basics (without framework) so you get a good understanding for PHP syntax and such before you jump into a framework like CodeIgniter. As your question stands right now, it is too broad, in that you are basically asking as how to use CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: How do you access a logged-in user's data for use throughout the site?

The logged-in user specific data is usually stored in a session. For codeigniter, you can access session data using `$this->session->userdata('item');`, or for example `$this->session->userdata('username');`.

However, if you are using a specific login system **it depends on the login system that you are using**.

---

**Custom Login System**

After receiving the login information from a login form, pass the data to the session using the following:

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Then refer to the username with the following:

```
$this->session->userdata('username');
```

See [Adding Custom Session Data](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) in the Codeigniter Documentation.

---

**Login System Example**

A popular codeigntier authentication library is [Tank-Auth](https://github.com/TankAuth/Tank-Auth).

When using Tank-Auth, after a user is logged in, you can call `$this->tank_auth->get_username()` (which calls `$this->ci->session->userdata('username')`, as mentioned above). This can then be stored and passed to a view.

In Tank-Auth you will see:

application/controller/welcome.php

```
$data['user_id']    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
$data['username']   = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
$this->load->view('welcome', $data);
```

application/views/welcome.php

```
Hi, <strong><?php echo $username; ?></strong>! You are logged in now.
```

Answer (score 0):

ok when user is logged in you need to store his or her data to session .
when you verify user get his or her data and store that in session.

```
$data = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata('logged_info', $data );
```

and then you can get it any where like

```
$userdata = $this->session->userdata('logged_info');
```

Comment: This question was answered hours ago, isn't it?